# How to add a method to a class from another file?

Tags: python, function, class, methods

How to add a method to a class from another file in python?
For example I have class `main` in file `main.py` and I have function `something` in file `method.py`. How could I make it so that class `main` has function `something` as a method?

Comment: in main.py, `from method import something`. python [imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: yes, but it is not going to add the function as a method of the class 'main'

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: I don't need a derived class but just a method added to a class that is not in the file where the function is defined (That's because my code would be a lot long)

Comment: `from method import something as ST; def something(): ST()`

Comment: thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

you need to add it dynamically (here an example where all your data are in the same file)

```
def function(p): return p

class A:
   def __init__(self): pass

# add as instance method
setattr(A, 'function', lambda  self, p: function(p))
# add as class method
setattr(A, 'function_cls', classmethod(lambda cls, p: function(p)))
# # add as static method
setattr(A, 'function_static', staticmethod(lambda p: function(p)))

print(a.function('p'))
print(a.function.__class__)

print(A.function_cls('p'))
print(A.function_cls.__class__)

print(A.function_static('p'))
print(A.function_static.__class__)
```

Output

```
p
<class 'method'>
p
<class 'method'>
p
<class 'function'>
```

The difference is that class and static methods can also be called from an instance as from a class

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: you can also change its name by changing the string parameter of setattr

Comment: If i should do something like a function that needs self parameter? like if it should return self.dosomething()?

Comment: self it is the price you have to pay to cast a function into a method, it carries the info of the instance. Try to remove it... and you get an error!

Comment: so i can only use static methods in that way?

Comment: updated answer now

Comment: That technique to add methods to an existing class is sometimes called monkey patching. You can add instance methods, but then the function you use has to take a 'self' parameter.

Comment: @Chris monkey patching is about evaluating string which contains commands, this should be just dynamic stuffs

Answer (score 0):

You can do the monkey patch by assigning a function to a member name of the class:

```
class Main:
    def existing(self): print(f"existing in {type(self)}")

# monkey patch (can be in another file)
def something(self): print(f"something in {type(self)}")
Main.something = something


aMain = Main()

aMain.existing()
aMain.something()

existing in <class '__main__.Main'>
something in <class '__main__.Main'>
```

This will also work in subclasses:

```
class Sub(Main):
    def other(self): print(f"other in  {type(self)}")

aSub  = Sub()
aSub.existing()
aSub.other()
aSub.something()

existing in <class '__main__.Sub'>
other in  <class '__main__.Sub'>
something in <class '__main__.Sub'>
```